# how to Publish / generate RSS feeds with dynamic contents

Tags: php, rss, feed

how to Publish / generate RSS feeds with dynamic contents. Are there any free software for publishing RSS feed for Webmasters.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Gourav.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you to use PHP with DOM classes for generating RSS feeds.
There is an example script: http://pastebin.com/BMymQ8DM

With DOM extension you can generate any XML document as you want.